# Determine location of a UIElement on a Canvas

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, uielement

I have spent 20 minutes trying to find an example in C# of how to draw a line between two rectangles, and I can't find anything.  I don't know if I just don't understand the paradigm of drawing 2D shapes in Silverlight, or if I'm just looking in the wrong place.

I have set up the rectangles so I can drag them around, and now I want to draw a line between the two shapes as I drag a rectangle across the canvas.  I want to be able to do something like this as I drag the second rectangle:

```
void host1_MouseLeftButtonMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (isDown) 
   {

      this.host1TranslateTransform.X = e.GetPosition(canvas).X - x;
      this.host1TranslateTransform.Y = e.GetPosition(canvas).Y - y;

      Line l = new Line();
      l.X1 = rect1.X; // does not work
      l.X2 = e.GetPosition(canvas).X;
      l.Y1 = rect1.Y; // does not work
      l.Y2 = e.GetPosition(canvas).Y;

   }
}
```

How do I get the coordinates of the first box?  I can't figure out how to get the coordinates of shapes relative to the canvas in my application.  I would appreciate any tutorials that give a beginner overview for how to draw simple 2D shapes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
Canvas.GetTop(element);
Canvas.GetLeft(element);
```

position properties are attached properties ;)